# Automate Selection of Optimum GARCH model in R

Tags: r

I've created 7 GARCH models in R (CIGarch1, CIGarch2, etc.) using the functions ugarchspec and ugarchfit.  I would like to automate the selection of the GARCH model with the lowest Akaike score and the model name to appear in my ugarchboot function.  I tried the following code:

```
# Create Akaike value table to find model with minimum score ----
CIGarch_Akaike_tbl <- data.frame(model = c("CIGarch1","CIGarch2","CIGarch3","CIGarch4","CIGarch5","CIGarch6","CIGarch7"),akaike_score = c(CIGarch1_Akaike, CIGarch2_Akaike, CIGarch3_Akaike,
                         CIGarch4_Akaike, CIGarch5_Akaike, CIGarch6_Akaike,
                         CIGarch7_Akaike))

# Looks for minimum Akaike value and returns the model name to be used in the following predict function
min_Akaike_Garch_model <- as.character(CIGarch_Akaike_tbl[which(CIGarch_Akaike_tbl$akaike_score==min(CIGarch_Akaike_tbl$akaike_score)),1])

# Predicting stock price with ugarchboot ----
# Update model based on best_Garch_model
CIpredict <- ugarchboot(min_Akaike_Garch_model, n.ahead = 10, 
                        method = c("Partial", "Full")[1])
```

I get the following error message:

> "Error in UseMethod("ugarchboot") : 
>     no applicable method for 'ugarchboot' applied to an object of class "character".

I've tried other `as.####` functions, but to no avail.  Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?